# How can I use a local variable after it has been returned?

Tags: python, variables, return, return-value, local

I am trying to create my own version of hangman. I have created a dictionary with the keys as context clues and the values are a list of words. I have made a function where I can find a random value from the valuelist of a random key, but when I try to use it outside the function I get an error saying that it is not defined even after I returned it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```py
import random

def random_phrase():
    """
    This function finds a random key (which is the type of phrase to be found) from the dictionary called categories and a random phrase from the list that corresponds to that key.
    """
    clue_phrase = random.choice(list(categories.keys()))
    print (clue_phrase)
    word_phrase = random.choice(categories[clue_phrase])
    return word_phrase 

random_phrase()

def phrase_of_blanks():
    blanks = ' '
    for i in word_phrase:
        if i == ' ':
            blanks += '  '
        else:
            blanks += '_' + ' '
    return blanks
phrase_of_blanks()
```

Comment: You cannot use a local variable outside of it's scope (unless it is captured as part of the enclosing scope in a closure, but nevermind that for now). The key thing to understand is that functions **do not return variables**. Functions *return objects/values*. You must capture that return value in the caller, e.g with another variable `foo = bar()`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

```
random_phrase()
```

Put

```
for i in random_phrase():
#in place of
for i in word_phrase:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the returned value in a variable,

Change

```
random_phrase()
```

To

```
word_phrase = random_phrase()
```